# Executing DDL statements inside Spark is slow and not in order

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, amazon-keyspaces

I'm trying to execute multiples commands with cqlSession inside spark, but the commands is very slow and didn't respect the order and fail to create the table. i need to wait delete to create a new table.

delete:

```
connector.withSessionDo(cqlSession => cqlSession.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person"))
```

create:

```
connector.withSessionDo(cqlSession => cqlSession.execute("CREATE TABLE IF EXISTS person(id text)"))
```

Comment: Can you include some minimal code sample which replicates the issue? Cheers!

Comment: delete and create are in methods exactly as code above. I call fisrt delete() after create().

Comment: @AlanMiranda Amazon Keyspaces performs ddl operations asynchronously.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/functional-differences.html#functional-differences.table-keyspace-management